# Compare Each Cell in 3D Array for N-Puzzle problem

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to compare the lists below, the first two integers represent the location of `0` or space within the grid. I want to compare each cell within goal[2]/test[2] and calculate the cells that match. In this case, only 5 would match as *location* matters. Any advice on how to do this efficiently?

```
goal = [0, 2, [[3, 2, 0], [6, 1, 8], [4, 7, 5]]]
test = [0, 0, [[0, 7, 1], [4, 3, 2], [8, 6, 5]]]
```

Comment: after comparing, do you want to get the location(s) where the values in both goal and test arrays matched? what you mean by "calculate the cells that match"?

Comment: Also, add to your question on what you have attempted so far, any python code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you want the result to be the index of the matched elements?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the zip() method twice:

```py
goal = [0, 2, [[3, 2, 0], [6, 1, 8], [4, 7, 5]]]
test = [0, 0, [[0, 7, 1], [4, 3, 2], [8, 6, 5]]]

for a,b in zip(goal[2],test[2]):
    for g,t in zip(a,b):
        print(g)
        print(t)
        print()
```

The code above only prints values on given places, but after slight modifications it should fit your requirements, however I'm not exactly sure what results do you want so I'll leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
# array data changed from the question to make
# the results more illustrative
goal = [0, 2, [[3, 2, 0], [6, 1, 8], [5, 7, 4]]]
test = [0, 0, [[0, 7, 1], [4, 1, 2], [5, 6, 6]]]

import numpy as np
g2 = np.array(goal[2])
t2 = np.array(test[2])
np.c_[np.nonzero(g2==t2)]
```

This gives:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 0]])
```

It means that there are two matching elements: one in row 1, column 1, and the other in row 2, column 0.